# How to block public access on S3 bucket while allowing my rest API and mobile apps to access the files

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

Use Case:
I want to be able to:

- Upload images and audio files from  my backend to S3 bucket
- List and view/play content on my backend
- Return the objects URLs in API responses
- Mobile apps can view/play the URLs with or without? authentication from the mobile side

Is that possible without making the S3 bucket public ?

Comment: Your backend is running on EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes. Hosted on Ec2

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible without making the S3 bucket public ?

Yes, it should be possible. Since you are using EC2 instance for backend, you, you can setup [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) to enable **private and secure access** of your backed application to S3. In the role, you would allow S3 read/write. This way, if your application is using AWS SDK, you can seamlessly access S3 without making S3 public.

Regarding the links to the object, the general way is to return  [S3 pre-signed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) links. This allows for **temporary access** to your objects without the need for public access. The alternative is to share your objects through **CloudFront** as explained in [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/). In either case, bucket can be private.